# get logs from docker after container restarted

Tags: docker, logging

I can see with

```
docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
65d84f86b878        dev-peer_dev_0-devcode-1.0-33c4b5969c38134419a7b74978cebe5797df6bb6a0d7f53257e9f532c889991e   "chaincode -peer.add…"   8 hours ago         Up 8 hours                                         dev-peer_dev_0-devcode-1.0
```

that my container restarted at 12:05 AM

When I do

```
docker logs 65d84f86b878 --since 24h
```

I can only see logs from 02:00 AM, so I can't find the cause of the restart.

Is it because it restarted, and I will only get logs from after restarting ? If so, is there a workaround ?

Comment: Not know what happened, but restart I guess will not delete logs, unless container id changes.

Comment: I just know it is up since 8h, I have no clue if it has just restarted, or created a new container

Comment: I think could use `docker ps -a` to see dead containers, if there is another container use something similar to `dev-peer_dev_0-devcode-1.0-33c4b5969c38134419a7b74978cebe5797df6bb6a0d7f53257e9f532c889991e` as image, then maybe a new container created, still can use `docker logs the_dead_container` to find the log. If the old container deleted, I guess no way to find any log. If still the old container but cannot find log, I don't know...

Comment: yep, I have no dead container, so I guess it restarted, but still no log before restart

Comment: No, as @deosha said, the container just new 8 hours ago. So there is something delete the old container, and then new a new container. So you have no chance to get the log this time. But for next time, you may need to reserve your log by your self to a bind-mount or some other place, you are not lucky this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This container is up since 8 hours and created since 8 hours. I guess this is your altogether different container from the same image.Old container  has fallen to your auto scaling rule trap. If you want to preserve logs or any data for that matter, you can mount your logs to volume on host during docker run and it will be preserved on that local file system

Comment: So old image should have been deleted ? I forgot an important detail,  I am using docker swarm....

Comment: Old container  has fallen to your auto scaling rule trap. If you want to preserve logs or any data for that matter, you can mount your logs to volume on host during docker run and it will be preserved on that local file system. Thanks to accept the answer if it works for you.